# How do I automate my webdriver to take data from excel sheet and use launch it?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi, build-automation

So I have written a script in selenium to launch a webpage and extract information like, title name, fitment, number of reviews, verify if some words are present in the page. For example I used this below code:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='text-m']")).getText();
System.out.println(text);
```

To get number of reviews in the page.

So What I am trying to do here is, I can launch one page at a time and get information. But I want to launch multiple pages, I have used TestNG for parallel execution but I was wondering if there is any way I can use excel sheet with multiple URL's and test them out one by one. Is there a way i can do this in selenium.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my Script to find the information on a page.

```
public void test1() throws InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("Test1");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.vikingbags.com/victory-high-ball-lamellar-large-leather-covered-non-shock-cutout-hard-saddlebags");
    if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Fit"))
    {
        System.out.println("Fitment Present");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Fitment not present");
    }
    if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Installation Instructions"))
    {
        System.out.println("Installation Instructions Present");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Installation Instructions Not Present");
    }

    if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Watch Installation Video"))
    {
        System.out.println("Watch Installation Video Present");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Watch Instaltion Video not present");
    }

    if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Mounting Hardware:"))
    {
        System.out.println("Mounting Hardware Present");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Mounting Hardware Not Present");
    }


    if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Patent Number:"))
    {
        System.out.println("Patent Number Present");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Patent Number Not Present");
    }

    if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Dimensions:"))
    {
        System.out.println("Dimensions Present");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Dimensions Not Present");
    }

    if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Storage Capacity:"))
    {
        System.out.println("Storage Capacity Present");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Storage Capacity Not Present");
    }

    if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Turn Signal Relocation Kit:"))
    {
        System.out.println("Turn Signal RK Present");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Turn Signal RK Not Present");
    }

    if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Weight:"))
    {
        System.out.println("Weight Present");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Weight Not Present");
    }

    if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Lid Opening:"))
    {
        System.out.println("Lid Opening Present");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Lid Opening Not Present");
    }
     String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='text-m']")).getText();
     System.out.println(text);
     System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.close();

}
```

In line number 4 `driver.get("URL you want to test")`. How do i change this using excel and use different links?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1- Use Testng Dataprovider to send URLs:

```
@DataProvider(name = "data-provider")
    public Object[][] urldataProviderMethod() {

    return new Object[][] { { "URL1" }, { "URL2" } };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "data-provider")
public void test1() throws InterruptedException {..
```

Option 2- By excel sheet:
Refer https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/import-data-from-excel-and-pass-to-data-provider.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I will definitely look into it and give feedback.

Comment: can i use excel sheet to provide different URLs?